# Mailto URL now not sending email

Tags: html, url, mailto

I have just built a landing page: growanimationstudios.instapage.com

In the bottom I have a button to send an email, in the editor I was asked for the URL to redirect and I inserted:

```
mailto:growanimation@gmail.com?subject=hello world
```

But as you can see in the live version it results in a error and no email is sent.

What am I missing??

Comment: *in the editor*..? What editor?

Comment: Please include all relevant code. Not just a link to your web page.

Comment: instapages, there is no code it is a drag and drop interface

Comment: This isn't really about programming then. SO is a **programming** Q&A site. Have you asked on an instapages forum?

Comment: @Liam although I agree this isn't prompting for a programming solution, OP presents a programming problem. The fact that his platform is a drag and drop interface doesn't mean that he shouldn't try to understand how the resulting code works. In fact, this is the right approach IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
mailto:growanimation@gmail.com?subject=hello%20world
```

You cannot use whitespace the way you tried. You have to encode to a url friendly format.

See [**w3schools**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) guide for URL encoding.

#### Option 1 - use of anchor

For an `<a>` tag, you could do:

```
<a href="mailto:growanimation@gmail.com?subject=hello%20world">Send</a>
```

If you have a `<button>` just wrap the above anchor in a button. Like this:

```
<button><a href="mailto:growanimation@gmail.com?subject=hello%20world">Send</a></button>
```

#### Option 2 - use of form

You could also accomplish what you want with the use of a `form`:

```
<form action="mailto:growanimation@gmail.com?subject=hello%20world" method="GET">
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

***or***

```
<form name="theForm" action="mailto:growanimation@gmail.com?subject=hello%20world" method="GET">
  <button onClick="document.getElementById("theForm").submit();">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I get the same error: 404. That’s an error.

The requested URL /?subject=hello%20world&submission=28014634 was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

Comment: Because you wrote `http://mailto:growanimation@gmail.com?subject=hello%20world`

The url for a mailto link is not hypertext (it's a tag for the client system to pickup), therefore the correct url is only:

`mailto:growanimation@gmail.com?subject=hello%20world`

I commented here because @Chris reply about encoding is also correct.

Comment: @GrowAnimation, I see you unaccepted this answer. Did it not work for you?

Comment: in the instapages interface I pasted the url you wrote, the problem is when I click on the button it adds the http:// automatically and gives an error

Comment: after reading zoubida13 comment I figured that maybe I could wait for another answer since your on did not work

Comment: @GrowAnimation which one did you try?

Comment: @GrowAnimation Instapage seems to support mailto links : https://help.instapage.com/hc/en-us/articles/205223568-Adding-Click-to-Call-Buttons-and-Click-to-Email-Links

So either you are using the wrong option in the interface to do it, or maybe you need to add a space as in their example 

`mailto: growanimation@gmail.com?subject=hello%20world`

Comment: @GrowAnimation, check [**this page**](https://help.instapage.com/hc/en-us/articles/205221768-Embedding-custom-HTML-or-widgets-into-an-Instapage-landing-page) on how to add custom HTML. Then, try any of the Option 1 codes I provided.